# How do you set icons of .exe files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, icons

Preferably using C++. Or a tool I can use from the command line. So far I've figured out how to extract icons from .exe files, but I can't set icons... Any suggestions?

Comment: what icons are you referring to? SetIcon( ) is one way to set an icon to for instance a button in your app after you load it from your resource file or are wondering about the default icon for your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a code sample that might help:

- [Change Icon of EXE file through code extracting it from other EXE file](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=643)

Answer (score 3):

If you want an icon to show in Explorer in a directory list, you'll need to add an icon to your app's .rc file. It must be the first icon in the resource file.

Do you want an icon to appear in the task bar and have it associated with your app's window? In this case you must set the hIcon member in your registered WNDCLASS structure.